# How to test a range of numbers with Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, redux, jestjs

I have:

```
const BOARD = {
  size: {
    columns: 5,
    rows: 5,
  },
}
```

and a Redux action creator that generates a position within the board's size:

```
const generateInitialPlayerPosition = (
  { 
    x = random(0, BOARD_SIZE.size.rows - 1), 
    y = random(0, BOARD_SIZE.size.columns - 1) 
  } = {}) => ({
  type: GENERATE_INITIAL_PLAYER_POSITION,
  payload: { x, y },
  }
)
```

I need to test that `generateInitialPlayerPosition` won't return any `x` or `y` greater than 4 in this case

Comment: Do you worry that `random(0, 4)` might return values greater than 4? If yes, you shouldn't. If no, then why do you need to write test cases for this? Whatever test you come up with will always pass (because `random(0, 4)` will not yield number greater than 4).

Comment: Where does `random` comes from? If it is an external module I would mock this.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Using methods [`.toBeGreaterThanOrEqual`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect.html#tobegreaterthanorequalnumber) and [`.toBeLessThan`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect.html#tobelessthannumber):

```
const value = ...
expect(value).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(lower_inclusive);
expect(value).toBeLessThan(upper_exclusive);
```

Answer (score 5):

If they are decimal numbers you can use [`.toBeCloseTo`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tobeclosetonumber-numdigits)

```js
test('adding works sanely with decimals', () => {
  expect(0.2 + 0.1).toBeCloseTo(0.3);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

here is my test:

```
it("should return a random integer between default range of (0,100)", () => {
  const result = getRandomInt();
  expect(result).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(0);
  expect(result).toBeLessThanOrEqual(100);
});
```